# Run a shell script without prompting for password

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo, password

I have a shell script that calls dpkg, which obviously needs to be sudoed to do anything. I've added dpkg to the list of files in /etc/sudoers.d that no longer require a password (Bad idea, I know), but when I attempt to run my script, it still requests a password. The script is simply

```
sudo dpkg -i $1
```

When I run dpkg from a terminal, it doesn't require a password, but when I do it from my .sh file, it just requests a password right away.

Any suggestions or idea as to what I need to do beyond the sudoers.d addition?

Comment: That literally IS the entire script. There's nothing at all that it does beyond that. I've ran the script via sudo script.sh, added it to the sudoers.d, and it still requests the password.

Comment: It starts with the #!/bin/sh. When I remove the sudo, it claims that it requires sudo before the dpkg. The goal is basically to pass in a path from another application, and then have it run the dpkg install to install the required package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was fairly simple. The issue is that the shebang line runs as a separate user account. As soon as I changed the `username usergroup = (root)...` to `ALL ALL = (root)...` in the /etc/sudoers.d directory, it then allowed us to run the script without requiring a password. Obvious security implications here, which need to be investigated, but this is outside the scope of the question I had originally asked.